# Access Files from URL Only, Not Directly by opening File link in Browser

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, dns, hosting

I have 2 hostings in one account with GoDaddy.

One hosting I use for my Wordpress website, and second hosting I use to keep my files related to website, to increase speed or performance.

But for the files in second account, I want to access only if request came from my first hosting or the website.

I searched couple of websites, and they suggested me that by using `htaccess` I can make it happen. But unfortunately none of them working. Some examples I am mentioning below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}!^https://thefreetools.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}!^http://www.thefreetools.com [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg¦zip¦js¦txt)$ - [F,NC]


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?thefreetools[NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?thefreetools.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|zip|png|js|css|bmp|exe|rar)$ https://thefreetools.com[R,L]
```

Or can I make it happen by manuplating DNS records of my GoDaddy Hosting.

PLEASE NOTE :- I AM USING SSL ON MY WEBSITE, SO URL STARTS WITH HTTPS

Comment: "I want to access only if request came from my First hosting" The Referer HTTP field can be trivially spoofed, there is no guarantee that it is the correct value so any kind of authorization schema build on top of it will fail at some point. Also "none of them working" is not a very detailed troubleshooting reporting, please make sure to give more details (even if I think your question is offtopic on this programming website).

Comment: "second hosting I use to keep my files related to website, to increase speed or performance." what does that mean? Why do you need a separate hosting to increase speed or performance? You may be creating problems yourself, why not put everything under one account/hosting? And if you really need to filter out access you need to put in place a true authorization schema, with a login or using "temporary" URLs.